# How to isolate and exctract specific values from an Excel spreadsheet in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv, spreadsheet

I have a .csv with a list of 5,000 .jpg filenames (column M). This list is a subsample of a larger spreadsheet comprising ~60,000 rows (column H). I wish to attribute the respective *'Altitude'* values (column K) to the relevant filenames in the subsample.

[image]

I have tried to achieve this within Excel without any results, how can I achieve this Pythonically?

Thanks,R

!!***RESOLVED***!!

Solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

subsample = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Laptop\Documents\Python\Subsample.csv', usecols = [1])
file = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Laptop\Documents\Python\Data.csv', usecols = [7, 10])

combine = pd.merge(subsample, file[['JPG', 'Altitude']], on='JPG', how='inner')
combine.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Laptop\Documents\Python\Altitude_Data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add a textual version of the first few rows and show what the desired output should be (it is not overly clear)

Comment: @MartinEvans Thanks for the response Martin! I have found a solutiuon using the 'pd.merge' command. I have appended this resolution to the original question asked above ^^ Thanks again